# How to ensure c# property with datetime type doesn't get set with datetime2?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I'm encountering the following error when I try to insert a table-valued parameter from ADO.Net:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
>
> The data for table-valued parameter "@ADGroupPreInsert" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.
>   SQL Server error is: 242, state: 3

The problem appears to be a `CreatedDate DateTime` property value that I'm extracting from a `List<GroupModel>` and including into the `DataTable`.

- `GroupModel.CreatedDate` is defined with a type of `DateTime`
- Its value gets set via some ETL logic
- The source value is of type `datetime2`

So in a nutshell, it looks like a property with a standard C# `DateTime` type will accept a `datetime2` value without issue but when this property value gets passed to SQL Server, SS will recognize this value as a `DateTime2` and throw an error if the target parameter or column in SS is defined as a `DateTime`.

How can I parse a DateTime property in C# to ensure that it doesn't have a `datetime2` value when passed to SS?

Comment: Does the error occur when you try to create a dateTime column or when you try to retrieve from it ?

Comment: Please reference [this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c30b3850-a72a-47d4-a197-21efe4afa0c0/mismatch-between-net-datetime-and-sql-server-datetime2-and-datetime?forum=csharpgeneral). It has to do with increased min and max values of datetime2 Vs C# DateTime type.

Comment: If possible, you should change your `DateTime` data type to `DateTime2`. For more information, read [Why You Should Never Use DATETIME Again!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdnsoldevs/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again/)